# what's the world record in finding the ground state of the 3D Ising model

Tags: ising-model, optimization

Finding the ground state of the 3D ising model (with no magnetization) is known to be NP-complete. Just wondering what is the biggest size cubic lattice someone has found the ground state of for this model?
dbm368

Answer (score 2):

While I don't exactly know which research group has the "world record" for simulating the Ising model at low temperatures (ground-state properties), I know that large system size exact (within statistical errors) computations can only be accessed via Monte Carlo approaches as you probably know. Then the question becomes : how many Ising spins (in a simple non frustrated system) can you simulate with Monte Carlo ? Perhaps the following paper will help you : http://www.sbfisica.org.br/bjp/files/v30_787.pdf. The answer is something of the order of billions of spins - Taking cube root of that gives you the linear size of the cubic lattice you can study !

Comment: I am not sure this is the same question OP asked. Searching for global minima is a quite challenging problem. If you use simulated annealing, the restriction comes from the simulation time at large system sizes.